# How should I implement one-to-one relationship in DynamoDB?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-dynamodb, one-to-one

We have split our Product and Price models, since both are fairly complex and they split over use-cases for editing and displaying.

I would like to give relatively direct access to some of the more common Price fields from Product, because the use-link-if-it-exists-and-create-it-if-it-doesn't logic comes up a lot and is moderately complex: I don't want to repeat the dozen lines for that in each of the ten places that might need it, test them all individually, and then have to remember to update them all if / when the logic changes.  It makes sense to me to put this logic on the Product, since I'm used to thinking of "price" as an attribute Products have.

Unfortunately, that means I'm trying to Inject / Autowire access to the PriceRepository on the Product class.  I get that's not a great idea, but it feels like all the ideas are bad.

We're using DynamoDB and Java with Spring Framework.  Here's a toy version of the class:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Product")
@Configurable
public class Product {
    private String id;
    private Price price;

    @Inject
    @Transient
    @DynamoDBIgnore
    private static transient PriceRepository priceRepository;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "Id")
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    public String getId() {return id}
    public void setId(String id) {this.id = id;}

    @DynamoDBIgnore
    public List<PricingOption> getPricingOptions() {
        setOrCreatePrice();
        return price.getPricingOptions();
    }

    public void setPricingOptions(List<PricingOption> options) {
        setOrCreatePrice();
        price.setPricingOptions(options);
    }

    public void setOrCreatePrice() {
        // simplified, skipping the cases when this.getId() returns null
        if (price != null)
            return;
        Price price = priceRepository.findOneByProductId(this.getId());
        if (price != null) {
            this.price = price;
            return;
        }
        price = new Price();
        price.setProductId(this.getId());
    }
}
```

Lookups of PricingOptions via Product are currently associated with adding products, updating products, choosing pricing options based on customer needs, entering marketing data, etc.  Each of those locations has a separate Bean and uses Products in a slightly different way.

This seems like it should be a fairly common sort of thing, but I don't see options that are consistent with OOP, DRY, and the way Spring is supposed to link things together. Maybe I should insert a common superclass for all the Beans which might need the data?  I'd appreciate some advice.

Comment: Could you explain why you've decided to make the "Price" its own object and not simply a primitive field of the product class? If you have lots of rules around how a price should be set why not put that logic in the "ProductsService" or simply place it inside the Product you have above if you prefer keeping your business rules in the data objects. With out more info that Price object looks like a little too much abstraction/encapsulation.  Do your Price objects exist outside of the product class anywhere else?

Comment: Price is a complex object, not just a scalar number.  It encapsulates a bunch of rules around bulk discounts, restrictions on availability & contracting requirements, etc. It was split into a separate model because we were concerned about performance: Most of the time, we don't need to get all the pricing + availability data for every product.

Comment: With regard to performance, you're adding an extra HTTP/REST request to retrieve the Price (Dyanmodb runs over HTTPS)... Your business rules are just complex private methods of the Product class.  Product.getPrice(Contract,Availability,....). Price itself does not seem part of your data model but part of your business rules (price calculation is not data). Your forcing it artificially into your data model which is why you find yourself needing a repository inside an ORM object. Maybe consider a POJO helper class PriceCalculator used inside Product if you want to encapsulate price logic.